# Xamarin forms: Getting NotImplementedException

Tags: xamarin.forms, uiswitch, notimplementedexception

I have a switch in my listview. In xaml, a converter added for the IsToggled property:

```
<Switch
          IsToggled="{Binding userProfileTO.userId, Converter={StaticResource isToggledConverter}}"
          HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

Converter code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool toggle = false;
    // My Codes
    return toggle;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Getting an NotImplementedException on ConvertBack when running this code.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in Myprojectname.dll
An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Myprojectname.dll but was not handled in user code
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Comment: You don't have the convertback method implemented, so it's normal you will get a NotImplementedException.

Comment: You are explicitly throwing a NotImplementedException, so of course you are getting a NotImplementedException.  It's doing EXACTLY what you are telling it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default binding type of `IsToggled` property is "`Two-way`".
That's why your `ConvertBack` function is getting called. 
You can simply remove the

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

in your `ConvertBack` method and everything will work fine.

Or if you don't wanna do that you can explicitly set the binding mode to be `One-way`

Comment: If I remove that code, what can I give instead of that? ConvertBack method should return value, is return false is enough?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604115/xamarin-forms-current-listview-switch-state-changing-when-the-listview-gets-ref#52605968

Comment: That will make your code error-prone, better to switch to One-way binding mode.